# NPAPI support in Firefox and Chrome actually dropped?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, firefox, npapi

Recently I've found out that Chrome and Firefox are dropping NPAPI plugins support by January 2013. Anyway, reading the blog messages with more attention, it seems that NPAPI plugins will be just disabled **by default** and not actually impossible to use.

What will happen? Will I be able to use my NPAPI plugin in Chrome/Firefox after January 2013? It's pretty complex enterprise plugin, so we would like to avoid reimplementing it.

[chrome dev's blog post](https://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html)

> Starting in January 2014, Chrome will block webpage-instantiated NPAPI plug-ins **by default** on the Stable channel.

[firefox dev's blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2013/01/29/putting-users-in-control-of-plugins/)

> To give people more control over their browser, Firefox will no longer activate most plugins **by default**.

I've also found another [post](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2013/09/24/plugin-activation-in-firefox/) on Firefox Dev's Blog, saying that I can try new plugin management system in Firefox Nightly. It was enough to set "Always Activate" to make the plugin work. Will this remain this way?

Comment: You say 2013 a number of times; the Chrome announcement is about 2014 and beyond.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrases "block by default" and "no longer active by default" are referring to things that look, in general, like the last post you linked to. Neither will make it impossible for users to use NPAPI plugins. They will require users to explicitly approve instantiation of NPAPI plugins.

However, the Chromium blog post also says: "Eventually, however, NPAPI support will be completely removed from Chrome." When that happens, it will be impossible to load NPAPI plugins in Chrome.

Comment: Seems it is removed in chrome 35.

Comment: Only on Linux; see the update at the bottom of the Chromium blog post linked from the question.

Comment: Update: chrome will actually drop NPAPI for good now http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html