# Chrome's Deprecation of the NPAPI & FireBreath

Tags: c++, google-chrome, printing, npapi, firebreath

According to [this](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html) statement, NPAPI is going to be destroyed (By Chrome)

> Starting in January 2014, Chrome will block webpage-instantiated NPAPI plug-ins by default on the Stable channel.

My company has a plugin written in [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home) (using C++) which I don't really know that much about, but its main purpose is to expose the underlying printer hardware.  But that is beside the point.

The [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home) website says

> A plugin built on FireBreath works as an NPAPI plugin or as an ActiveX
>   control (windows only) and support could be added for other plugin
>   types built in C++ as well.

**My questions**

Is it safe to assume that come January 2014 that the plugin written with [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home) will no longer work in the Chrome browser?  If true, is there another cross-browser option I could use to expose the underlying printer hardware?

Comment: Hmm. Let me google that for you. Looks like Firefbreath isn't going to work with PPAPI anytime soon - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebreath-dev/1rWmoM8oZY0

Comment: This is actually a better link: http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Browser+Plugins+in+a+post-NPAPI+world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any existing Firebreath plugin uses NPAPI, and will thus be blocked by default. This isn't the same as not working at all, which will come later; see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457786/npapi-support-in-firefox-and-chrome-actually-droped).

The links in the comments above are probably the best resource for discussions of future options for a cross-browser framework to do what you want. However, before you can reasonably figure out what the best replacement technology for your case is, you'd need to know more about what the plugin does, because there's no one-size-fits-all replacement for all of NPAPI (by design).