# Using vlc npapi plugin in chrome in linux

Tags: vlc, npapi

I want to use vlc web plugin on chrome in linux but this post says that chrome has stopped supporting npapi plugins. https://askubuntu.com/questions/487399/install-vlc-plugin-on-chrome

I am using vlc plugin in chrome on windows 7 and it works fine. I can see vlc web plugins when I do about://plugins.
But in Ubuntu 14.10, I cannot use vlc web plugin in chrome. I am able to use it on firefox, so its installed.

1. Is it true that chrome has taken down the support for npapi plugins
2. If yes, why I am still able to use it on windows but not on linux

Any help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NPAPI support in Firefox and Chrome actually droped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457786/npapi-support-in-firefox-and-chrome-actually-droped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems off-topic for SO, but:

1) On Linux, yes, it is the case that [NPAPI is no longer supported in Chromium](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/xEbgvWE7wMk).

2) Because the technical reasons for dropping NPAPI support early on Linux did not apply to Windows.