# VLC web player not working in Google chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, vlc

I am using VLC web player in my video portal. It's working absolutely fine in Firefox and Opera but its not working in Google Chrome.

I know VLC installs Mozilla / ActiveX plugin while installation of VLC in computer which helps Mozilla and other ActiveX supported browsers to play the videos on web. But how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457786/npapi-support-in-firefox-and-chrome-actually-droped/19459200#19459200

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NPAPI plugins, including VLC, are [no longer supported in Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html). If you are building a site that you want to work in Chrome, you'll need to use standards-based solutions (in this case, the`<video>` element).

Answer (score 0):

try reenabling NPAPI:

enter the following into chromes addressbar: chrome://flags/#enable-npapi

click on enable and restart chrome

-- hope it helps !!

Comment: This is not a solution for someone building a site, since a) every user would have to do this, and b) it will only work until September.